# How to provide access to protected endpoint with provided client id and client secret?

Tags: java, spring, oauth, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have an application with OAuth. 
Authentication contains 2 steps: get access token, make a request with provided access token.

Is it possible to configure spring security to provide access by provided client id and client secret as request params like https://localhost.com/api/endpoint?client_id=xxxx&client_secret=yyyy?

Comment: Isn't your proposed scheme just HTTP Basic authentication? Why use OAuth at all?

Comment: It's not quite HTTP Basic, but it's not a scheme anyone would recommend in practice (credentials in the URL). HTTP Basic would be better.

Comment: github have the same option https://developer.github.com/v3/#oauth2-keysecret for server-to-server connection

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple as always:

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints
            .tokenGranter(new CompositeTokenGranter(
                            Arrays.asList(resourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter(), clientCredentialsTokenGranter())))
            .authenticationManager(providerManager())
            .clientDetailsService(clientDetailsService())
            .tokenServices(defaultTokenServices());
}

private TokenGranter resourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter() {
    return new ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter(
            new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(authenticationProvider())),
            defaultTokenServices(),
            clientDetailsService(),
            defaultOAuth2RequestFactory());
}

private TokenGranter clientCredentialsTokenGranter() {
     return new ClientCredentialsTokenGranter(
             defaultTokenServices(),
             clientDetailsService(),
             defaultOAuth2RequestFactory());
}
```

I added new CompositeTokenGranter with list of 2 granters: ResourceOwnerPassswordTokenGranter (for authentication by clientId+clientPassword+username+password) and ClientCredentialsTokenGranter (for authentication by clientId+clientPassword).

**EDIT**

Looks like my question was incorrect. Sorry about this. I made that changes for authorization server. So it works for /oauth/token only.
How to fix question problem I have no idea for now but I will update this question when found solution.

Comment: Must have been a different question than the one I read. I'm happy you are happy though (since the default token granter already has those 2 options).